# Where to find the complete comparison of document management features between share point 2016 and older version

Tags: 2013, 2016, document-management

HI what are the main improvements related to document management,record management and database enhancements in SharePoint 2016 comparing to SharePoint 2013 & 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists some feature comparisons, but none that apply exclusively for document management features. Therefore here is a summary of them.

**Document View Threshold changes**

Prior to 2016, a Document Library would have a limited view for 5000 items. This design practice still exists, but 2016 adds an automatic creation of Indexed Columns which prevents possible documents becoming inaccessible. All in all, the end-users shouldn't need to worry about this design rule anymore.

**Increased file-size limit on uploads**

Documented to be limitless, Microsoft's suggestion is to have files with a file-size of maximum 10 Gb uploaded due to possible performance issues.

**Improved mobile access views**

The new mobile access views support touch-screen document management.

**Durable links**

If a document's name changes, it can still be accessed by using the same *durable* link, assuming you have Office Web Apps with your installation.

**Keyboard shortcuts for documents**

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> = **New**
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> = **Edit**
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> = **Upload**
- etc.

**Added announcements and callouts when working with documents**

E.g. in document upload process.

**Expanded support for special characters in file names**

> SharePoint has historically blocked file names that included the &, ~, {, and } characters, file names that contained a GUID, file names with leading dots, and file names longer than 128 characters. These restrictions are removed in SharePoint Server 2016 and are now available to use.
>
> Restricted characters such as % and # are still not allowed in file names.

**Previews for media content**

Images and videos can be previewed by hovering over the file in a Document library

**Support for open-office file formats**

ODF formats allow non-Ms products to be used when working with documents.

---

**Notes:**

- I've excluded e.g. search improvement changes, as they apply for O365, and not for SharePoint on-premise
- Also excluded OneDrive-specific changes, such as an added feature for deletion policy and folder-view improvements

---

**Sources**

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346121(v=office.16).aspx
- https://en.share-gate.com/blog/whats-new-in-sharepoint-2016