# What are the discontinued functionalities between SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, features

I've tried to come up with a comprehensive listing of functionalities that have existed in SharePoint 2013 Server, but do not exist in SharePoint 2016 Server. The only MS's material I've hit has been this [Feature availability across SharePoint standalone plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx#Feature%20availability%20across%20SharePoint%20standalone%20plans), which concerns features. I've also seen (and [conducted](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214325/where-to-find-the-complete-comparison-of-document-management-features-between-sh/216695#216695) related) lists of added and improved functionalities, but they don't exactly point out the no-longer available ones.

I'd be happy to be guided towards a comprehensive listing of the discontinued functionalities, but also any observed findings are welcome to be added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Deprecated features**

- **User Profile service (ForeFront Identity Manager Client)**

  - SharePoint Server 2016 no longer uses FIM as the synchronization client.
    FIM (synchronize between Active Directory and SharePoint) is being removed and
  - the bidirectional sync with AD has been improved.
  - The default process is Active Directory Import.
  - You can also use any synchronization tool such as Microsoft Identity Manager 2016.
- **STSADM.exe**

> The Stsadm command-line tool has been deprecated, but it is included
>   to support compatibility with previous product versions.

- **Tags and Noted**

> They are completely deprecated.

- **SharePoint Foundation.**

> SharePoint Foundation is no longer available in the SharePoint Server
>   2016 release.SharePoint Foundation 2013 remains available for use.

- **Standalone Install Mode.**

> SharePoint Server 2016 doesn’t support the standalone install
>   option.(See the first improvement in this article)

- **Excel Services.**

> Excel Services and its associated business intelligence capabilities
>   are no longer hosted on SharePoint Server. Excel Services
>   functionality is now part of Excel Online in Office Online Server.

- **The Work Management Service Application**.

> You couldn’t now aggregate tasks to a central location on SharePoint
>   because the Work Management Service Application has been removed.

- **My Tasks and associated Exchange Task Sync features.**

> They have been removed because the Work Management Service Application
>   that is required for both features has also been removed.

- **BI Capabilities.**

> The SQL Server 2014 Power Pivot and Power View add-ins for SharePoint
>   Server 2016 cannot be deployed or used in SharePoint Server 2016. To
>   deploy these add-ins you need to upgrade to SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.1

- **InfoPath 2013 and SharePoint Designer 2013**

> It will be the last versions of those products.However, the support
>   for InfoPath 2013 and SharePoint Designer 2013 will match the support
>   life cycle for SharePoint Server 2016, running until 2026.

Find the complete list in my article at [SIMPLY, WHAT’S NEW AND DEPRECATED IN SHAREPOINT SERVER 2016 ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/whats-new-in-sharepoint-and-project-server-2016-in-simple-words/)

Comment: A listing like this is superior. I can immediately spot mentions which do not appear in the MS's material linked in the other answers, which is what I'm the most interested about.  I'm curious if you have to add anything from your own findings? (Also, consider formatting the list as quoted, as it is a quoted one ;-) )

Comment: What about your opinion now :) ?!

Comment: Regarding my own findings specifically were in Project Server and I have also documented here in my blog https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/29/simply-whats-new-and-deprecated-features-in-project-server-2016/

Comment: Thanks for the addition. The formatting is exemplary as well. I'll accept this as the answer supplements the MS's documentation, yet still includes the ones mentioned there.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback :)

Answer (score 3):

here is technet article which will give you some highl level stuff: [What's deprecated or removed from SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112(v=office.16).aspx)

The following features and functionality have been deprecated or removed in SharePoint Server.

- Duet Enterprise for Microsoft SharePoint
- SharePoint Foundation
- Standalone Install mode
- ForeFront Identity Manager client (FIM)
- Excel Services in SharePoint
- Tags and Notes
- Work Management Service Application
- Stsadm.exe

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Additionally, I'm curious if you have to add anything from your own findings? I feel that such undocumented changes are considered almost usual nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the articles

[Deprecated or removed features from SharePoint 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112(v=office.16).aspx)

[New and improved features in SharePoint 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346121(v=office.16).aspx)